# Terminate threads when SIGINT is called - C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I'm building a generic program written in C-UNIX (using Linux so I don't care about BSD or WIN functions), that creates two threads to handle the communication with a server.

```
void init_threads(int socket_desc) {

    pthread_t chat_threads[2];

    ret = pthread_create(&chat_threads[0], NULL, receiveMessage, (void*)(long)socket_desc);
    PTHREAD_ERROR_HELPER(ret, "Errore creazione thread ricezione messaggi");

    ret = pthread_create(&chat_threads[1], NULL, sendMessage, (void*)(long)socket_desc);
    PTHREAD_ERROR_HELPER(ret, "Errore creazione thread invio messaggi");

}
```

Since this program will be launched from shell I want to implement the CTRL-C possibility and so did I with this line of code:

```
signal(SIGINT,kill_handler);
// and its related function
void kill_handler() {
        // retrive threads_id
        // call pthread_exit on the two threads
        printf("Exit from program cause ctrl-c, bye bye\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
```

My question is how can I found out the thread ids inside the event handler function and is it correct to call pthread_exit or should I use something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly terminate a thread in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950621/how-to-properly-terminate-a-thread-in-a-signal-handler)

Comment: The signal is delivered to the main thread; just exit() there, the os will do the cleanup for you.

Comment: I swear I really did not found the duplicate after 20 minutes of deep search. Reputed the answer of Felix Palmen better than the comment of @Ctx because in my program I am using sockets and if there's a connection opened on them the sockets will remain open for a short period even if threre's none to listen. Anyway, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `pthread_exit()` from a signal handler! It is not required to be *async-signal-safe*, see [signal-safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

In general, you should do *as little as possible* in a signal handler. The common idiom is to just set a flag that is periodically checked in your main loop like e.g.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t exitRequested = 0;

void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    exitRequested = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    // init and setup signals

    while (!exitRequested)
    {
        // do work
    }

    // cleanup
}
```

Also, use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) for installing signal handlers. See [`signal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) for reasons not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links and explaination

Comment: I know that's unrelated to my question, but could you explain to me what is the sig_atomic_t type and why did you use that instead of an int? I know that integer is 4 byte on 32bit machines, this is tighter?

Comment: It's a type that guarantees reads and writes with a *single* instruction. There's a good chance that it's just a `typedef` to `int`, but there might be systems where `int` needs more than one instruction to read/write (e.g. on an 8bit architecture where `int` has 16 bits) -- for a consistent value between signal handler and main program, just always use `volatile sig_atomic_t`.